# FC on Map Activity on end call?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview, onresume

I have a map view in my activity it works fine when there is no call. So obviously there is an `onResume()` , well at least that is what my log cat is saying. I want to know what I am missing for my map view to resume properly.

**LogCat**

```
05-06 18:47:28.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4869):     at www.Freshapp.com.Thumper.html.Thumper.onResume(Thumper.java:307)
```

**onResume()**

```
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "[ACTIVITY] onResume");

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, new GeoUpdateHandler());


 super.onResume();
```

**Line 307**

```
 super.onResume();
```

Am I missing something?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just added a uncaught exception to my `onResume()`.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

super.onResume() needs to be the first thing you call in your onResume() method.  Move that to the top.

Comment: Alright, should it be before the ` Log.i(TAG, "[ACTIVITY] onResume");`?

Comment: Still a force close any other sugestions?

Comment: Yes - before.  Can you post more of the stack trace?